# Removing only the last whitespace in string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, trim

How can I remove only the last whitespace (if there is any) from  the user input? example:

```
var str = "This is it   ";
```

How can I remove the last like 1-4 whitespaces but still keep the first 2 whitespace (between this, is and it)

Question solved - thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimRight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a function like this:

```
String.prototype.rtrim = function () {
    return this.replace(/((\s*\S+)*)\s*/, "$1");
}
```

call:

```
str.rtrim()
```

Addition if you like remove all leading space:

```
String.prototype.ltrim = function () {
    return this.replace(/\s*((\S+\s*)*)/, "$1");
}
```

Comment: Should I do something like this:

str = str.rtrim(); ?

Comment: @BeHaa yes, you should

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know if it was helpful.

```
    var str = "This is it  ";
    alert(str.replace(/(^[\s]+|[\s]+$)/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery trim for that,

```
var str = "This is it   ";
$.trim(str);
```

Comment: .trim() is not support in all browsers, if you want it work, you should write your own function!